# How to parse a file and get specific variables and add them in a list in python?

Tags: python, parsing

What I'm trying is to read a file and get specific variables so I can later use and compare them.
What I have now:
    file_1.py:

```
some imports

#TypeA
var_1 = ("some code...", name_type = typeA_1)
var_2 = ("some code...", name_type = typeA_2)
...
#TypeB
var_3 = ("some code...", name_type = typeB_1)
var_4 = ("some code...", name_type = typeB_2)
```

the script I have:

```
def section(my_file, begin, end):

    with open(my_file) as f:
         for line in f:
             if line.startswith(begin):
                for line in f: 
                    if line.startswith(end):
                       return
                    yield line.rstrip() 

def main():

    vars = []
    name_types = []
    with open('file_1.py', 'r') as f:
         file_content = f.readlines()
         for line in file_content:
             fields = line.split('=')
             vars.append(fields[0].split()[0])
             name_types.append(fields[2].split()[0])
```

I would like to get the var_1, var_2, var_n and the corresponding name_type for each var and for each section(TypeA and TypeB). So far this doesn't work very well... and I got bit stuck now, so any help or advice would be great.

Comment: If `file_1.py` really is a Python file, why not just import it?

Comment: can you add the function calls for both functions `main()` and `section()` . and also add file_1.py data